Does changing an email of connected app's user has impact on integration?
I have a connected app and a need to change an email of integration user that is connected with this app. What/If anything needs to be taken into account to avoid any downtime?

You can see from the ConnectedApp metadata type that the Email field

contactEmail  string  Required. The email address that Salesforce uses to contact you or your support team.

You can see from the Basic Connected App Settings in Help

Enter the contact email for Salesforce to use in case we want to contact you or your support team. This address isn’t given to Salesforce admins who install the app.

So clearly, changing the value has no impact on integrations
